# Android mediaplayer play a Songs as orderly

Tags: android

I am new to Android. In my app MediaPlayer plays groups of songs in order. The songs are stored in one arraylist and the song names are stored in another arraylist..

```
for(i=0;i< songarray.sizeof();i++)
{
  mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,(Integer) songarray.get(i));

  sname.setText(songname.get(i));
  mp.start
}
```

The problem is that the songs play only one then print one song name.

Comment: Which one is played? The last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a listener to the end of the song, and then start the next one (BTW - what's `sizeof()`):

```
int index = 0;
sname.setText(songname.get(i));
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,(Integer) songarray.get(i));
mp.start(); //as per @iturki comment
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
        mp.release();
        if (i < (songarray.size() - 1)) {
            i++;
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,(Integer) songarray.get(i));
            sname.setText(songname.get(i));
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mp.start();            
        }           
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Just you need to add `mp.start` to start the first song.

Comment: don't use a for loop. only an if, so you would play once song at a time.

Comment: thank u very much... it's working.. where i am relese player  after last song played

Comment: The first line in the listener releases the player anyway :)